# Unable to get teams message attachment content using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am able to get message attachment information as shown below but unable to download the file content which is stored in share point site.

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "id": "fc323b65-2cee-48d9-9574-0e26eb74e9bb",
            "contentType": "reference",
            "contentUrl": "https://otdeveloper.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Shared Documents/General/1Ex.txt",
            "content": null,
            "name": "1Ex.txt",
            "thumbnailUrl": null
        }
    ]
```

I am using the following get call for the above request with auth token

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{{TeamId}}/drive/root:/Test/Shared Documents/General/1Ex.txt:/content
```

I tried the solution posted in
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/200
but I am getting 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check [Get message API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).You will receive the the attachments info in the response as shown below[image]

Comment: I already getting the content URL response as mentioned in the question but my question is  does graph API support fetching the content using the content URL as it is still beta?

Comment: Are you trying to get info of the attachment present in the share point?

Comment: I am trying to get the content of the attachment present in share point.content url in my case is " https://otdeveloper.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Shared Documents/General/1Ex.txt/"

Comment: Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT the API you have mentioned has stopped working now. I have an application for MS Team and was using the "/content" API, to get the content from Teams. But since 2 months it just shows 404, I've no clue how to resolve this. Can you please guide us into the right direction?